# How many common item

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Let's say we have these information:

UPDATE

> ```
> Group A - Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
> Group B - Item 1, Item 3
> Group C - Item 3, Item 4
> ```

I'd like to know which groups contains the most common items:

Output:

> ```
> Group A - (Item 1 and Item 3)
> Group B - (Item 1 and Item 3)
> ```

What algorithm would you use?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are the _common items_ common because they appear a lot overall, or common because they are shared with another group?

Comment: @AustinHastings not exactly: A and B share 67% of sum A and B items (without repeats - this should be clarify by the 
author)  - they are Item 1 and Item 3. For A and C it is 25% and it is Item 3. For B and C they share 50% and it is Item 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to represent the dataset:

```
data[A] = {1,2,3}
data[B] = {1,3}
data[C] = {3,4}
```

It is better to use numbers so you can use for loops, counters, etc.. so:

```
data[0] = {1,2,3}
data[1] = {1,3}
data[2] = {3,4}
```

then I would have another data structure with a counter of how many matches between groups you have, so for example matches[A][B] = 2, matches[A][C] = 1 and so on. That is the data structure that you will need to calculate. If you do that, then your problem is reduced to finding the maximum value in that data structure.

```
for i = 0; i < 3; i++
   for item in data[i] 
      for j = 0; j < 3; j++
         //optimize a little bit (match[A][A] doesn't make sense)
         if j == i
            next
         if item in data[j]
            matches[i][j]++
```

Of course you can optimize this some more. For example, we know that matches[A][B] is going to be equal to matches[B][A], sou you can skip those iterations.

Answer (score 0):

So given a list of groups and their contained items, you want to output the identities of the all the groups that have the same, maximum number of items in common with one other group.

Let's get a list of groups and items:

```
group_items = (
    ('Group A', ('Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3')),
    ('Group B', ('Item 1', 'Item 3')),
    ('Group C', ('Item 3', 'Item 4')),
    )
```

Then let's store the *max # items shared* value for each group, so we can collect all matching groups at the end. We'll also track the *max of the maxes* since we can (rather than go back and re-compute it).

```
max_shared = {item[0]:0 for item in group_items}
num_groups = len(group_items)
group_sets = {}
max_max = 0
```

Now we're going to have compare every group with every other group, but we can ignore certain comparisons. As @Perroloco mentions, comparing Group A with Group A isn't useful, and computing intersect(A,B) is symmetric with computing intersect(B,A), so we can range from 0 to N and then from i+1 to N, instead of doing 0..N cross 0..N.

I'm using the `set` data type, which costs *something* to construct. So I cached the sets because we aren't modifying the membership, just counting the membership of the intersection.

It's worth pointing out that while intersection(A,B) == intersection(B,A), it is not the case that the MAX for A is the same as the MAX for B. Thus, there are separate comparisons for the inner max and the outer max.

```
for i in range(num_groups):
    outer_name, outer_mem = group_items[i]

    if outer_name not in group_sets:
        group_sets[outer_name] = set(outer_mem)

    outer_set = group_sets[outer_name]
    outer_max = max_shared[outer_name]

    for j in range(i+1, num_groups):
        inner_name, inner_mem = group_items[j]

        if inner_name not in group_sets:
            group_sets[inner_name] = set(inner_mem)

        inner_set = group_sets[inner_name]

        ni = len(outer_set.intersection(inner_set))

        if ni > outer_max:
            outer_max = max_shared[outer_name] = ni

        if ni > max_max:
            max_max = ni

        if ni > max_shared[inner_name]:
            max_shared[inner_name] = ni

print("Overall max # of shared items:", max_max)

results = [grp for grp,mx in max_shared.items() if mx == max_max]

print("Groups with that many shared items:", results)
```